# Google Maps and D3.js

Tags: google-maps, d3.js

I've got this working on on a previous project but I've come across a stumbling block replicating it with new data which is a puzzle.

The points are rendering but not in the right place.  Also, when you zoom in and out the points change position - I've double checked that long and lat are the same.

I think the problem is in the transform function:

function transform(d) {

```
          d = new google.maps.LatLng(+d.Latitude, +d.Longitude);
          d = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(d);
          return d3.select(this)
              .style("left", (d.x - padding) + "px")
              .style("top", (d.y - padding) + "px");
```

}

Is fromLatLngToDivPixel(d) placing the points wrong or is something overriding the left and top styles?   Any help greatly appreciated.  Here is the 'not yet' working example - code is on gist.github.com.

https://bl.ocks.org/BMPMS/36dfbe319f6a6f4cfb56205e95687024

Answer (score 1):

P.P.S I've solved it.  CSS, silly of me not to guess.  Required CSS as follows - Hygiene being the class of each individual layer :

```
 .hygiene, .hygiene svg {position: absolute;}

 .hygiene svg {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.hygiene circle {
   fill: #DC143C;
   stroke: grey;
   stroke-width: 0.5px;
}
```